# Dual monitor color calibration

Tags: colors, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to get my monitors (two different models) to look the same. I've been fiddling with the gamma/brightness/color channels in the NVIDIA Control Panel, but I can't make them look exactly the same.

When I use comparison images, it's always just slightly off. Is there some free tool out there that can do this process for me? I don't know if the contrast, brightness, or whatever is off. My perception is apparently pretty bad.

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: If you really want the monitors to look "exactly the same", then there is no free "tool".  You need to use a colorimeter instead of your eyeballs.